# Помогите разобраться с ручным управлением в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Вообщем мой слайд автоматом крутит. Пытаюсь добавить ручное управление но не работает в чем проблема не пойму?! Вот ссылка: http://jsfiddle.net/Arty21/4e6kG/2/

Вот код руч.управления:

```
$("#next").click(function(){ 
if(nowslide>=slide) { 
$("#slide").animate({"marginleft":"-=500px"},speed);
 nowslide += 1; 
} else { $("#slide").animate({"marginleft": 0 +"px"},speed); 
now_slide++;
 } 
});
```

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример слайдера. По ссылке направильно добавленный код, плюс тупо черный экран в окне просмотра результата.

Comment: margin**L**eft или "margin-left"

Comment: ручное управление в жквери - это здравый смысл и православный джаваскрипт, энджой!